# Set inequality with functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A \to B$ with $X\subset A$ and $Y \subset B$. I'm trying to prove

> $X \subset f^{-1}(Y) \implies f(X) \subset Y$.

Note that $f^{-1}(Y)$ denote the inverse image of $Y$. I've been element chasing for a while and don't seem to bet getting anywhere. Could I get a hint please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really is just the definition:

If $x \in f^{-1}(Y)$, then there is some $y \in Y$ such that $f(x) = y$. In particular, $f(x) \in Y$. It follows that $f(X) \subset Y$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe it's just time for me to head to bed!

Comment: @user240146: We all hit that point sometime :-).

Answer (score 1):

Let $y \in f(X) \Rightarrow y = f(x)$ for some $x \in X \Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(Y) \Rightarrow f(x) \in Y \Rightarrow y \in Y \Rightarrow f(X) \subset Y$.